# How to set PKHUD above inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

Is there a way to keep HUD above inputAccessoryView?

**See This**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Have you tried **SVProgress Hud** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the HUD above the keyboard you have to do this:

`HUD.show(.progress, onView: UIApplication.shared.windows.last)`
[image: HUD above keyboard]